# Format the content of file

Tags: bash, awk

I have to format the contents of my file. so that if i pass in .csv file 1st column - [SUCCESS]/[FAILURE], 2nd column - *co.com, 3rd column- content
Just wanted to keep contents in one line with adding comma as below

```
[SUCCESS] abc.co.com
This is 1st content,,,,/
asdfmmmm

[SUCCESS] abcdd.co.com
This is 2nd content
cabjdhds

[SUCCESS] abcasd.co.com
This is 3rd content...?/
cajbhjwd b

[FAILURE] ab.co.com
This is 3rd content...?/
cajbhjwd b
```

Expected output

```
[SUCCESS], abc.co.com, This is 1st content,,,,/ asdfmmmm............

[SUCCESS], abcdd.co.com, This is 2nd content cabjdhds..........

[SUCCESS], abcasd.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b.........

[FAILURE], ab.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b
```

Tried below, but this prints all in one line

```
cat file |awk 'BEGIN {accum_line = "";} /^[[a-z]+]/{if(length(accum_line)){print accum_line; accum_line = "";}} {accum_line = accum_line " ," $0;} END {if(length(accum_line)){print accum_line; }}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=", "
}
/^\[/{
  $1=$1
  $0=$0","
  if(val){
    sub(/, $/,"",val)
    print val}
    val=""
  }
{
  val=(val?!/^\[/?val " ":val:"")$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    sub(/, $/,"",val)
    print val
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding explanation for above now.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                  ##Starting BEGIN section of this code here.
  OFS=", "                              ##Setting OFS as ", " for all lines here.
}                                       ##Closing BEGIN block here.
/^\[/{                                  ##Checking condition ig a line starts from [ then do following.
  $1=$1                                 ##Resetting $1 to value $1 to make OFS value in affect here.
  $0=$0","                              ##Concatenating , in current line.
  if(val){                              ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
    sub(/, $/,"",val)                   ##Substituting , and space at last of line with NULL in variable val.
    print val}                          ##Printing variable val here.
    val=""                              ##Nullifying variable val here.
  }
{
  val=(val?!/^\[/?val " ":val:"")$0     ##Creating variable val and concatenating its value with its own previous value along with space if line DO NOT start from [.
}
END{                                    ##Starting END block of this awk code now.
  if(val){                              ##Checking if val is present then do following.
    sub(/, $/,"",val)                   ##Substituting , and space at last of line with NULL in variable val.
    print val                           ##Printing variable val here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Mic15, ok sure fixed it now, please check and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want the newline between each output line or not, you can do this several different ways, e.g.

```
awk -F] -v n=0 '
    NF==0 {n=0; print "\n"; next} 
    {   printf n ? ", %s" : "%s]", $1
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
            printf n ? ", %s" : ",%s", $i
        n++
    }
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Where you make use of the `']'` as the field separate to split the only line with `']'` and then keep a counter and use `printf` to append each of the lines until an empty line is reached.

**Example Use/Output**

Preserving the empty-line you have between each line of output, you can just copy/middle-mouse-paste at the command line to test, e.g.

```
$ awk -F] -v n=0 '
>     NF==0 {n=0; print "\n"; next}
>     {   printf n ? ", %s" : "%s]", $1
>         for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
>             printf n ? ", %s" : ",%s", $i
>         n++
>     }
>     END {print ""}
> ' file
[SUCCESS], abc.co.com, This is 1st content,,,,/, asdfmmmm

[SUCCESS], abcdd.co.com, This is 2nd content, cabjdhds

[SUCCESS], abcasd.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/, cajbhjwd b

[FAILURE], ab.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/, cajbhjwd b
```

**Eliminating The Additional Comma**

If you really want to accumulate all but the first record in the group, you could do something like:

```
$ awk -F] -v n=0 -v acum="" -v OFS="" '
>     NF==0 {n=0; print ",", acum, "\n"; acum=""; next}
>     NF>1 {
>         printf n ? ", %s" : "%s]", $1
>         for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
>             printf n ? ", %s" : ",%s", $i
>         n++
>     }
>     NF==1 { acum = acum " " $1; n++ }
>     END {print ",", acum}
> ' file
[SUCCESS], abc.co.com, This is 1st content,,,,/ asdfmmmm

[SUCCESS], abcdd.co.com, This is 2nd content cabjdhds

[SUCCESS], abcasd.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b

[FAILURE], ab.co.com, This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting Record Selector to nothing `RS=""` and recreate Record `{$1=$1}` you can use `gnu awk` like this:

```
awk '{$1=$1","}1' RS="" OFS=" "
[SUCCESS], abc.co.com This is 1st content,,,,/ asdfmmmm
[SUCCESS], abcdd.co.com This is 2nd content cabjdhds
[SUCCESS], abcasd.co.com This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b
[FAILURE], ab.co.com This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b
```

If you need a blank line between record:

```
awk '{$1=$1","}1' RS="" OFS=" " ORS="\n\n" file
[SUCCESS], abc.co.com This is 1st content,,,,/ asdfmmmm

[SUCCESS], abcdd.co.com This is 2nd content cabjdhds

[SUCCESS], abcasd.co.com This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b

[FAILURE], ab.co.com This is 3rd content...?/ cajbhjwd b
```

Comment: I like this, it's very short, Is it possible to add a comma in the same command?

Comment: @Mic15 Comma added.